# Can I go to USA under the multiple visa from Canada, where I hold a student visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I am holder of a student visa for Canada. Prior to obtaining my Canadian student visa, I visited the USA and Canada on visitor visas. My multiple entry visa for the USA is still valid. Can I go as a student visa holder to the USA under the old multiple entry visa?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 1):

My wife was in a similar situation when she was a student, in Canada. She was able to go to the States from Canada under her visitor visa and just had to clarify which visa she was re-entering Canada on as both her student visa and tourist visa for Canada we valid.